# Why are all my mpi threads masters?

Tags: c++, mpi

I am starting out with MPI and have written a quick demo program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int myRank = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank);
    if (myRank) {
    cout << "slave" << endl;
    }
    else {
    cout << "master" << endl;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I run it with the following command:

```
aprun -n 4 test
```

My output is

```
master
master
master
master
```

I was expecting something like

```
slave
master
slave
slave
```

Why is this happening? Why are all my threads masters?

Comment: "If" is only true for "0" and false for every other integer values?
try to check MPI_SUCCESS and MPI_ERR_COMM ?

Comment: The return value of the MPI_Comm_rank function is not what you think it is. The value returned is an error code.  This is true for most MPI* functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
int myRank = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank);
```

You should not assign myRank to the result of the call to MPI_Comm_rank. Just do:

```
int myRank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank);
```

and it will work.

Comment: Yes indeedy, OP's code seems to assign the return value of the call to mpi_comm_rank to myRank. If a successful call returns 0 and if 0 has the value 'false' when considered as a boolean, myRank will be false.

Comment: This is rather embarrassing, but at least MPI_Comm_rank returns no errors :-)

Comment: @Misha: Faulting MPI functions call `MPI_Abort()` by default - you would never see anything different than `MPI_SUCCESS` unless you manually set the error handler on the communcator to `MPI_ERRORS_RETURN`. That's why in normal MPI applications you would never need to check the return value and the error value argument to the Fortran MPI subroutines is made optional in MPI 3.0.